# Action based controller using reflections

Tags: java, mvc, reflection, controller

I'm modeling a reflection-based controller. I would like to know if you agree with my implementation and about what could be enhanced.

I'm starting with reflection and I would like to know if I'm using good practices.

```
public class StartController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String vars = req.getParameter("mvc");
            ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

        MainController main = new MainController();
        main.RESTProcess(req, resp, context, vars);
    }
}

public class MainController extends Controller {

    public void RESTProcess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, ApplicationContext context, String vars)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String[] url;
        int nvars;

        String controller = null;
        String action = null;;
        String[] params = null;
        int i;
        int n;

        String controllerName;
        String actionName;

        if(vars == null || "".equals(vars.trim()))
        {
            this.redirect(resp,"home");
        }
        else
        {       
            url = vars.split("/");
            nvars = url.length;

            if(nvars > 0)
            {
                controller = url[0].trim(); //users
                if(nvars > 1)
                {
                    action = url[1].trim(); //edit
                    if(nvars > 2)
                    {
                        n = 0;
                        params = new String[nvars - 2]; //array[0] = 5 (iduser)
                        for(i = 2; i < nvars; i++)
                        {
                            params[n] = url[i];
                            n++;
                        }
                    }
                }


                controllerName = this.getFirstUpper(controller) + "Controller"; //HomeController, UserController pattern
                if(!controllerName.equals("Controller"))
                {
                    actionName = "action" + this.getFirstUpper(action); //actionIndex, actionEdit pattern
                    if(!action.equals("action"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Class classe = Class.forName("com.sample.controller." + controllerName);
                            try
                            {
                                Constructor c = classe.getConstructor(HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class, String[].class);
                                try
                                {
                                    Object obj = c.newInstance(req, resp, context, params);

                                    Method m = classe.getMethod(actionName, null);
                                    m.invoke(obj, null);

                                    System.out.println(obj.toString());
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.redirect(resp,"home");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getFirstUpper(String str)
    {
        Integer x = str.length();
        str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(str.substring(1, x));

        return str;
    }
}

public class UserController extends Controller {

    private HttpServletRequest req;
    private HttpServletResponse resp;
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private String[] params;

    public UserController(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, ApplicationContext context, String[] params)
    {
        this.req = req;
        this.resp = resp;
        this.context = context;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public void actionEdit()
    {
        Long id = Long.valueOf(this.params[0]);
        System.out.println("/home/edit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would make some changes to `getFirstUpper()`:

> ```
> public String getFirstUpper(String str)
> {
>     Integer x = str.length();
>     str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(str.substring(1, x));
>
>     return str;
> }
> ```

The name `x` is not a very good name as it's only a single character.  I'm not even sure if a separate variable is needed for this, but if so, consider renaming it to `stringLength`.  The type should also be `int` instead, which is the return type of [`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29).  Either way, you can just pass `length()` directly into `substring()` (in place of `x`).

It's also unnecessary to create a `str` variable if the inner function's return value is just going to be returned right away.  Plus, it's already known that this method is supposed to return a `String`.

```
return str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(str.substring(1, str.length()));
```

I also have a general comment regarding curly braces:

[The Java standard dictates the use of "Egyptian braces,"](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style) which involves putting the opening brace on the same line as the statement, rather than the next line by itself:

```
public String getFirstUpper(String str) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only few general comments from me:

1. Start your method names with lowercase.
2. Remove excess `try` keywords.
3. Catch only specific type of `Exception`s!

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the reasoning behind your proposals. While they are all good, the motto of CR is *"teach a man how to fish"* and not *"give a man a fish"* ;)